# From where to get the Official Indian Governmental Map of India in R?

Tags: r, maps, raster, r-sf, r-raster

**I am trying to find the official Indian Government-acceptable MAP of India**.

I am comparatively new to `r` .. So far I have tried `highcharts` & **`GADM` with `geom_sf`** to plot interactive **Indian Map** but both of them have provided **Indian map** which is **not acceptable in India**.

[image]

---

### Where as Microsoft Excel shows a proper Indian Map

(**update:** Compare the top part of the Maps to note the difference ):

[image]

`Highchart` provided an alternate link https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jaL7q5x3/2/ when it was raised in this SO post [How to get right Map for India in highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619571/how-to-get-right-map-for-india-in-highcharts)

**Which unfortunately cannot be directly used** in `r` `highcharts` or may be i don't know how to do it & when downloaded `json` of this from the above link then it is **unusable in r** due to unnesting of coordinates column issue and raised it below SO post.

[How to unnest fields in json that contain map coordinates int list column in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749168/how-to-unnest-fields-in-json-that-contain-map-coordinates-int-list-column-in-r)

All I want to do is to use official map of country and it has been couple of weeks since I am trying to find **official map of India** to use it in an **interactive dashboard shiny application:** https://vineet-sansi.shinyapps.io/IndiaCovid19Dashboard/ and has been unable to do so.

A country that resides **~20% population of the World & I still can't find its acceptable Map by using r**

---

#### UPDATE: Map & Link to Indian Govt. website that displays the Map used in India & by Indian govt.:

https://indiamaps.gov.in//soiapp/

https://bharatmaps.gov.in/

https://mapservice.gov.in/BMSA/LoginModule/index.aspx

stategisportal.nic.in/stategisportal

schoolgis.nic.in

postalgis.nic.in/view

findmybank.gov.in/FMB

surveyofindia.gov.in/documents/polmap-eng-11012021.jpg

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain a bit the "not acceptable in India" part? The GADM is usually a good source (it has some licensing aspects, but I don't think you are referring to that).

Comment: If you could see the top part of the Map used in `GADM` & in `excel` you will see the difference. And here is the link to the Map that is used in one of the **Indian Govt. websites**: https://surveyofindia.gov.in/documents/polmap-eng-11012021.jpg

I am not a geo spatial background person so not sure from where can I get Map that is used or approved by Indian govt & public.

And I could face objection for using the map provided by GADM as that is not the MAP of India used by Indian govt.

Comment: For anyone who can't see the difference, its about disputed areas in the North, Ladakh and Jammu & Kashmir. For more info, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India

Comment: These are some of the govt weblinks for the maps that I have come across:  
https://indiamaps.gov.in//soiapp/ 
https://bharatmaps.gov.in/ 
https://stategisportal.nic.in/stategisportal/ 
https://schoolgis.nic.in/ 
http://postalgis.nic.in/view/
http://findmybank.gov.in/FMB/

Comment: If your problem is solved with these sources (i.e. official/acceptable map of India), please provide your solution as answer for others. Provide how you downloaded the map and read it into your visualisation to create the map you aimed for. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ray, My problem is not yet resolved and even I am looking for solution from anyone as I am new to `geospatial` & `Gis files`. If someone can show me how to use data from these `weblinks` or `r libs` to recreate similar map then I will definitely share my code and final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have solution for this issue & it may help several other people like me who were looking for **official Indian Government map of India**.

(Please ignore if I have used any wrong jargon in this or if there are other better ways to do then please share your answer as I am not a `geospatial` person).

**1.a** **Download zip file containing geojson, shapefile etc. of India** you can checkout below weblinks of datameet:

[datameet link1](http://datameet.org/indian-shapefiles-central/)

[datameet link2](http://projects.datameet.org/maps/)

[datameet link3](http://projects.datameet.org/maps/states/#shapefile-attributes)

[datameet link4](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/in/)

[datameet github link for more Indian data including maps](https://github.com/datameet)

But this seems to come with some **license** which is probably free to use & require to credit the originator but I am not sure and would suggest you to read more about it on the above links and do you own cross check.

(**UPDATE Additional sources:**

1.b came across `geojson` file on one of SO post [Is there any way to draw INDIA Map in plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60910962/is-there-any-way-to-draw-india-map-in-plotly)

source: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jbrobst/56c13bbbf9d97d187fea01ca62ea5112/raw/e388c4cae20aa53cb5090210a42ebb9b765c0a36/india_states.geojson

1.c As per the tweet reply from **surveyofIndia** Country level boundary `.shp` files can also be downloaded from https://surveyofindia.gov.in/pages/public-awareness. Waiting for another reply for **Country level map with state boundaries** & will update the link once i get the reply)

**2.** **After downloading zip file from datameet link & extracting** you will get multiple files & folder in this and I have used just couple of them below and you may try more for your needs.

using file `maps-master\\Country\\india-soi.geojson` from downloaded zip file

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(geojsonio)
    library(broom)
```

```
    ind_soi <- geojson_read("E:\\3. R\\India shape file downloaded\\maps-master\\Country\\india-soi.geojson", what = "sp")
```

tidy your data as per (https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/325-background-map-from-geojson-format-in-r.html)

```
    ind_soi <- ind_soi %>% 
      broom::tidy()
```

```
    ind_soi %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
             color = "white") + # fill = "grey", 
      geom_polygon() +
      ggthemes::theme_map() +
      coord_map()
```

[image]

It doesn't display `States` but atleast I know that it has proper shape boundary of the country Map.

3. **Create Indian Map with States** by using `.shp` file from **downloaded zip file** (using maps-master\States\Admin2.shp)

```
    library(rgdal)
    library(sf)
```

```
    ind_states <- st_read("E:\\3. R\\India shape file downloaded\\maps-master\\States\\Admin2.shp")
    
    ind_states %>%
      st_as_sf() %>% 
      
      ggplot() +
      geom_sf() +
      theme_map()
```

[image]

Comment: Weel done, ViSa. Thanks for posting that answer and pointing out the checking of the license. Highly appreciated. Feel free to accept your answer!

Comment: Thanks @Ray for appreciating. I have also got a tweet reply from one of the Department **ministry handles** & they have shared a link: `https://surveyofindia.gov.in/pages/public-awareness` but it contains `.shp` files only of **Country outer boundary** & not of states. Hopefully will get another reply soon with link to States boundary as well.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone looking for a topojson of world map where India has shown with Indian government defined boundaries can refer the below file:

https://gist.github.com/dwannat/24d6e65c6770faad006e3f613036deb4

Comment: https://github.com/wri/wri-bounds/blob/master/dist/in_countries.zip