# How to have default NULL value in Input & filter data only when non null value?

Tags: r, shiny

**Desired Result:** I am trying to **display/plot all the data by default** with **NULL value in selectInut** by default and **filter data** only when when some **non null input value** is selected in `selectInput` `shiny` app.

I came across [Force no default selection in selectInput()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175997/force-no-default-selection-in-selectinput) SO post to add **NULL values** to the `SelectInput` and it worked only partially for me till now.

**Issue:** It only works when I select some non nulll value otherwise produces blank output (seems like **if else failure here could be due to reactive()** function but I am not sure why that is happening).

---

#### code below:

ui

```
selectInput(inputId = "vaccine_center_state_select",
                         label = "Select State to narrow your search", 
                         choices = c("",unique(vacc_centers$state))
                         ,selected = NULL 
                         ,multiple = FALSE
             ),
```

server:

```
filtered_vaccine_centers <- reactive({
    
    req(input$vaccine_center_state_select)
    
    if(!is.null(input$vaccine_center_state_select))
        
        {
            filtered_vaccine_centers <- vacc_centers %>% 
            filter(state == input$vaccine_center_state_select)
        
        }
    else filtered_vaccine_centers <- vacc_centers
        
    
    }) %>% 
        bindCache(input$vaccine_center_state_select)
```

Comment: @Vineet, One friendly advice, it is just illegal, in India to use unapproved map and is liable to penal actions.  Read `Section 79(3)(b) of IT Act of India`.  Second, I remember you posted a xml data extraction problem few days back.  Is that solved?

Comment: Thanks @AnilGoyal appreciate your advice & help, from days I have been posting on `SO` about the **latest correct Indian Map availability sources** & its only recently (yesterday & today) I have got to know about the correct map sources & will be updating with the correct Map of India tonight itself. Here is my post for correct map request which finally I have answered for everyone else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67847391/from-where-to-get-the-official-indian-governmental-map-of-india-in-r/67851281?noredirect=1#comment119938325_67851281

Comment: @AnilGoyal, thanks for the `upvote`, already in process to update my code with latest map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I made couple of changes .. not sure which one was the factor

1. Instead of `null` used other text i.e "No State selected" & applied condition on it:
2. changed dataframe name `filtered_vaccine_center` to `filtered_vaccine`

ui

```
selectInput(inputId = "vaccine_center_state_select",
                         label = "Select State to narrow your search", 
                         choices = c("No State selected",unique(vacc_centers$state))
                         ,selected = "No State selected" 
                         ,multiple = FALSE
             ),
```

server:

```
filtered_vaccine_centers <- reactive({
    
    req(input$vaccine_center_state_select)
    
    if(input$vaccine_center_state_select != "No State selected")
        
        {
            filtered_vaccine <- vacc_centers %>% 
                                filter(state == input$vaccine_center_state_select)
        
        }
    else filtered_vaccine <- vacc_centers
        
    
    }) %>% 
        bindCache(input$vaccine_center_state_select)
```

points of Vaccination Centers on lat, long axis without using country map coordinates

**Output**

[image]